# to display name in the popup instead of hello message from the following code.

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

I have this code

```
<object data="data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgiSGV

 sbG8iKTs8L3NjcmlwdD4="></object>
```

the output of this whn I pass on is a popup which says hello..

My question is , how can we get our name instead of"hello" message

Thank you for the help , much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple base64 encoded message.

You can decode this with [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.atob)

```
atob("PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgiSGVsbG8iKTs8L3NjcmlwdD4=");
// <script>alert("Hello");</script>
```

If you would like to encode your own script in base64, you can use [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.btoa)

```
btoa('<script>alert("NewAndroidTechie");</script>');
// PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgiTmV3QW5kcm9pZFRlY2hpZSIpOzwvc2NyaXB0Pg==
```

---

Note, `atob` and `btoa` will not work in all web browsers. If you would like a more reliable solution, I would recommend using a server-side script.

Here's a decoding solution for node.js

```
var b = new Buffer("PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgiSGVsbG8iKTs8L3NjcmlwdD4=", "base64");
b.toString();
// <script>alert("Hello");</script>
```

And the encode counterpart

```
var b = new Buffer('<script>alert("NewAndroidTechie");</script>');
b.toString("base64");
// PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgiTmV3QW5kcm9pZFRlY2hpZSIpOzwvc2NyaXB0Pg==
```